# present and past perfect with a dead entity

Tags: grammar, tense, grammaticality

I learned that "had", or past perfect is usually used with a dead entity. But what if I am not trying to emphasize the fact that an action had taken place before that entity died? Such as:

> My dead grandfather has stepped on a mine (when he was alive).

This sentence is resultative, showing why he died, and uses present perfect.

And this sentence below:

> My dead grandfather stepped on a mine (on July 6, 1995).

This sentence is incorporating the specific date at which he stepped on a mine, therefore using simple past tense.

Are the uses of simple past and present perfect tense above valid?

Comment: Time-references, if any, in a present-perfect construction cannot exclude the present. "when he was alive" excludes the present no less than "July 6, 1995" does, and so the present-perfect is a no-go.

Comment: @TRomano Okay. I thought it's possible because to me it was telling the result of stepping of a mine, which continues to hold to this day, the death.

Comment: Consider: *I **have been** to London. I **went** there two years ago.* Any explicit time-reference in the sentence "overrides" the implicit conversational context. You must look at each clause individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Present perfect only works for things your grandfather can still do.  If he can longer do it use simple past.

Things grandpa can no longer do --

> My dead grandfather stepped on a mine [*when he was still alive*]
>
> My dead grandfather fell off a horse [*on July 6, 1995*].

Things grandpa can still do --

> My dead grandfather has lain in the grave for over forty years.

Comment: If you want a "resultative" sentence, showing why he died, you have many options but I don't think verb tenses will directly help you solve the issue.  A sentence like, "Stepping on a mine killed my grandfather," would work.